# bootstrap-editable is returning me the old value instead of new

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I have a table with bootstrap and editable using bootstrap-editable.

When I click in a cell and I am trying to change the value using calendar, in success event of editable I do `$(this).html()` and returns the old value instead of to give me the new value.

```
$('TABLE TD A').editable({
    type: 'date',
    name: 'test',
    language: "es-ES",
    pk: $(this).attr("pk"),
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Cambiar Fecha',
    success: function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass("bold");
        ...
    }
});

$.mockjax({
    url: '/post',
    responseTime: 200
});
```

I dont understand why. Could somebodey tell me some weay to correct it?

Comment: Are you not using x-editable?  The problem might be fixed by [upgrading to x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolved it,

It is curious the solution.

I added a new parameter in success function like:

```
...
success: function (e, newValue) {
   ...
}
...
```

And in newValue I have the value I want.

curious solution. What I don't understad why in e parameter is empty and they use a second parameter to do it.